# Curl amazon EC2 instance getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

Hi I have been using Amazon Ec2 server and I am trying to call to this server using curl from another server(php) which is hosted in godaddy.

While calling I am getting the below error

```
Error: "Failed to connect to ec2-**-**-**-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 8080: Connection refused" - Code: 7
```

Can anyone tell me about what is the actual issue.

Note: While trying to connect this through rest api tool it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the security group for the ec2 instances has the inbound rule from Goddaddy's IP range or set to all (0.0.0.0/0) with port 80 and 443.

Comment: I have changed as you told but still i am not getting any data. 
But I can get data while i hit that url in bowser

Comment: Always it is showing 
Curl error: Failed to connect to ec2-**-**-**-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: make sure, you open the port 8080 as well.